# Updating ListField in django models?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I have following model for which i want to update team which is a list:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length =100 )
    team = ListField(models.CharField(max_length =100),null=True)
```

I know I can first fetch the team attribute of object and the append the new value to list and then update the object with new list , but is thr any other way for updating ListField?

Comment: Nobody knows, because you haven't told anyone what ListField is (hint: it's not part of Django).

Comment: @DanielRoseman It's a field that is part of Django-nonrel which currently has a backend for appengine and mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For appending a value to a list, you want to use a `$push` operator on the `team` field.
The django mongoDb engine has a hook for it:

http://django-mongodb.org/topics/atomic-updates.html

And here is the documentation on how to use the `$push` operator in mongodb:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push

Hope this helps.